# Google Sheet Query shows "Min" in Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

I am using the Google Sheet Query Language to get unique values from one Spreadsheet to another. Following directions online, I did something like this:

```
=QUERY(SheetName!A1:D1002,"Select A,min(B),C,D group by A,B,C,D")
```

However, when I do this, the word `min` appears on the sheet. I can't figure out how to remove it. Any advice?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=QUERY(SheetName!A1:D1002,"Select A,min(B),C,D group by A,B,C,D label min(B)''")
```

or:

```
=QUERY(QUERY(SheetName!A1:D1002,"Select A,min(B),C,D group by A,B,C,D"), "offset 1", )
```

or:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(SheetName!A1:D1002,"Select A,min(B),C,D group by A,B,C,D"), 2)
```